Not able to display json content inside html file in Angular

Blockquote

[![enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.ne


import { Component, HostListener, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NewrequirementService } from '../../new-requirement/services/newrequirement.service';
import { PopupComponent } from 'src/app/Components/Core/popup/popup/popup.component';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { AuthService } from '../../auth/services/auth.service';
import { User } from '../../auth/Models/user.mode';
import { DashboardService } from '../services/dashboard.service';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-financedashboard',
  templateUrl: './financedashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./financedashboard.component.css']
})
export class FinancedashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  user?:User;
  gridApi: any;
  notificationCount: number = 0;
  userid ?:string;
  email?:string;

  popupVisible: boolean = false;
 userid1?:string;
  popupTop: string = '0px';
  popupLeft: string = '0px';

  noti: Notification[] = [];
 
  togglePopup() {
  
    this.popupVisible = !this.popupVisible;
   
  }
 

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  onClick(event: MouseEvent) {
    const target = event.target as HTMLElement;
    
    // Check if the click event target is the notification icon/button
    const isNotificationIcon = target.matches('.notification-container') || target.closest('.notification-container');
    if (!isNotificationIcon) {
      // Toggle the popup if the notification icon/button is clicked
      this.popupVisible =false;
      return;
    }

    // Check if the click event target is outside the popup
  
  }



  constructor(private newcustomrerequirementservice: NewrequirementService, private dialog: MatDialog, private authservice:AuthService, private dashservice:DashboardService) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.user = this.authservice.getUser();
   console.log(this.user);
this.email =this.user?.email

if (this.email) {
  this.authservice.getUserID(this.email).pipe(
    switchMap((response) => {
      this.userid = response;
      console.log('UserID:', this.userid); // Log the user ID
      // After getting the userid, make the next API call
      return this.dashservice.getNotificationcount(this.userid);
    })
  ).subscribe({
    next: (notificationCount) => {
      this.notificationCount = Number(notificationCount);
      console.log('Notification Count:', this.notificationCount); // Log the notification count
      // Fetch notifications
      this.fetchNotifications();
    },
    error: (error) => {
      console.error('Error fetching notification count:', error); // Log the error
    }
  });
}



if (this.email) {
  this.authservice.getUserID(this.email).pipe().subscribe({


    next: (response) => {
      this.userid = response;


    }
  });




  

  
}























    this.newcustomrerequirementservice.getNewcustomerRequirementtobeauthorizedbyfinancemanager().subscribe({
      next: (response) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        this.rowData = response;
      },
      error: (error) => {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
    });
  }
  columnDefs = [
    { headerName: 'CRID', field: 'crid', sortable: true, filter: true, floatingFilter: true },
    { headerName: 'Customer', field: 'customername', sortable: true, filter: true, floatingFilter: true },
    { headerName: 'Division', field: 'divisionname', sortable: true, filter: true, floatingFilter: true },
    { headerName: 'Date', field: 'date', sortable: true, filter: true, floatingFilter: true },
    { headerName: 'Status', field: 'statusname', sortable: true, filter: true, floatingFilter: true },
    { headerName: 'Approved/Rejected', field: 'approvedrejectedstatusname', sortable: true, filter: true, floatingFilter: true },
    {
      headerName: 'Actions',
      cellRenderer: (params: any) => {
        const button = document.createElement('button');
        button.innerText = 'Approve';
        button.style.backgroundColor = 'aliceblue';
        button.style.width = '100px';
        button.style.height = '40px';
        button.addEventListener('click', () => this.onButtonClick(params.data));
        return button;
      }
    }
  ];

  rowData: any[] = [];

  onGridReady(params: any): void {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
  }

  onButtonClick(rowData: any): void {
    alert(`CRID: ${rowData.crid}`);
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(PopupComponent, {
      width: '250px',
      data: { message: rowData.crid, uid: this.userid} // Pass any data to the popup if needed
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
      // Handle any actions after the popup is closed
    });




  }


  fetchNotifications(): void {
    if (this.userid) {

   alert(this.userid);

   this.dashservice.getNotifications(this.userid).subscribe({

      
    next: (response) => {
 
    this.noti = response;
      console.log(this.noti);
    },
    error: (error) => {
      console.error('Error fetching notifications:', error);
    }
  });













    }
  }


  
}



<div class="container">
  <div class="notification-container">
    <app-notification-icon [notificationCount]="notificationCount" (click)="togglePopup()"></app-notification-icon>
    <div class="popup" *ngIf="popupVisible">
      <h3>Notifications</h3>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Notification ID</th>
            <th>Created Date</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let cu of noti">
            <td>{{ cu |json}}</td>
       
        
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ag-theme-alpine">
    <ag-grid-angular 
      style="width:auto; height: 300px; border: 1px solid black;color:black"
      class="ag-theme-alpine"
      [rowData]="rowData"
      [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
      (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
    ></ag-grid-angular>
  </div>
</div>

this  is my html file here i am able to display the json  as shown in picture ...but when i try to access individual items it is showing error {{ cu.id}} is showing error ..
How i can  display individual items in json file ...my Model interface is
export interface Notification {
    id: number;
    description: string | null;
    doctype: string | null;
    docId: number;
    customerRequirement: any | null;
    taskInitiation: any | null;
    identityUser: any | null;
    notificationby: string | null;
    createddate: string;
  }


Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?  In this case 95% of your images only shows TEXT, and the added value of the IMAGE is (very!) small.

UPDATE:
The import for Notification was not imported, the inbuilt notification has no id field hence you are getting this error.

I think since it initially has a null or undefined, access a property of undefined, will give you an error. To avoid this we need to null check the value before accessing it, for this we can use the typescript safe navigation operator (?.) to prevent the error.
...
<tr *ngFor="let cu of noti">
    <td>{{ cu?.id }}</td>
</tr>
...


still it is showing error .

@LakshmiSureshan Could you share what error you are getting?

Compiled with problems:
×
ERROR
src/app/Components/features/financedashboard/financedashboard/financedashboard.component.html:15:24 - error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Notification'.
15             {{ cu?.id }}
~~
src/app/Components/features/financedashboard/financedashboard/financedashboard.component.ts:11:16
11   templateUrl: './financedashboard.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component FinancedashboardComponent.

@LakshmiSureshan Please share the TS code also

yes now  I  have shared ts file also

@LakshmiSureshan There is no import for notification in the ts code, could you check that, also if its imported correctly, try restarting the dev server

.Thanks for the help. I renamed the Notification model to Notifications and imported the model correctly. I think there is predefined class called Notification. Now it is working fine.
